# Any lib to manipulate class names in React

Tags: reactjs

All:

**[UPDATE] Dont no why, but after I remove all node module and install again, it works!**

I wonder if any one can give a example how to operate on React component class names?

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var classnames = require("classnames");

var Alert = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
// this part I do not know how to do, it does not work
//        var classNames = classnames({
//          "alert": true
//        });
    return (
      <div style={styles} className={classNames}>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Alert>Hello</Alert>,
  document.getElementById("content")
);
```

I tried to install react-classset, but every time, the npm says:" The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"

I am not sure what this means, does it mean this lib has been deprecated?

Any thought?

Thanks

Comment: Packages can have peer dependencies. These are other packages (mostly with a certain version number or version range) that a package depends on. A peer dependency will not automatically be installed, so you will have to do this yourself. From the message that you provided, my expectation is that the (already installed) React package does not have the required version.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart Thanks, any clue how to find the package not satisfied the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any addons you can do normal string manipulation like this:

```
var Alert = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }

    var classNames = true ? "alert" : "base";

    return (
      <div style={styles} className={classNames}>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Otherwise, legacy react class functionality can be found inside [github.com/JedWatson/classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage)

install with `npm install classnames`

*[deprecation notice](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html)*

Comment: I tried to install classnames, but every time, the npm says:" The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"  I am now using windows7

Answer (score 1):

The official recommendation from the [React blog post about the 0.14 release in the breaking changes section](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#breaking-changes) is to use the [classnames package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). (The `classSet` addon was deprecated with a warning in 0.13 and removed for 0.14.)

Comment: I tried to install classnames, but every time, the npm says:" The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!" I am now using windows7